# type-safe useDispatch with redux-thunk

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using `redux-thunk` to use async action creators. The result is also returned to the respective caller.

```
function fetchUserName(userId: number): Promise<string> {
  return Promise.resolve(`User ${userId}`)
}

function requestUserName(userId: number) {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    return fetchUserName(userId).then(name => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SET_USERNAME',
        payload: name,
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This way, the store is updated, while allowing the components to handle the response directly.

```
function User() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(requestUserName(1))
      .then(name => {
        console.log(`user name is ${name}`)
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        alert('failed fetching user name')
      })
  }, [])
}
```

This is working as intended, but it will not be compiled by TypeScript due to invalid types.

1. The `dispatch` returned by `useDispatch` is not recognized as a function that returns a Promise and so TypeScript argues that `Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<void>'.`.
2. Even if it would be recognized so, the Promise should be correctly typed

How can this situation be solved?

It would be perfectly fine for me to create a wrapper around `useDispatch` or to redefine the type of `dispatch` but I have no idea how that type should look like in this particular situation.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`useDispatch` returns the `Dispatch` type [used by Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-usedispatch-hook), so you can only dispatch standard actions with it. To also dispatch thunk actions, declare its type as [`ThunkDispatch`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/813b633b4cccb83fdd14da015424a1a5aed3026c/src/index.d.ts#L20) (from `redux-thunk`).

`ThunkDispatch` receives type parameters for the store state, [extra thunk args](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument) and your action type. It allows to dispatch a [`ThunkAction`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#usage-with-redux-thunk), which basically is the inner function of `requestUserName`.

For example, you can type it like this:

```
import { ThunkDispatch } from "redux-thunk";
import { AnyAction } from "redux";

type State = { a: string }; // your state type
type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<State, any, AnyAction>; 
// or restrict to specific actions instead of AnyAction

function User() {
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(requestUserName(1))
      .then(...)  // works now
  }, []);
  ...
}
```

`AppDispatch` can also be [inferred](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-usedispatch-hook) from the store with `typeof store.dispatch`:

```
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch, ThunkMiddleware } from "redux-thunk";

const mw: ThunkMiddleware<State, AnyAction> = thunk;
const dummyReducer = (s: State | undefined, a: AnyAction) => ({} as State);
const store = createStore(dummyReducer, applyMiddleware(mw));

type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch // <-- get the type from store
```

[TS Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=4&ssc=69&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSGcAvnGVBCHAERSoYsDcAsAFChIsXAWIARYITAoYaABa16jZmw4wAtOwAm%20AB7d%20g6PDwSpM%20dgCCAOwCeVjMAg3sadjKQBlGNCTYUMDAAGzsAWWAtLWCkAHcUdkUGJlZtPQMBcGM4GDl8GwBrbDwAFTzCs2lZOWwy-IKIqJj4xLpklTTddVz6jP4yfKcXeiRqgFViKAA5FBAkAAoiJCgASS0ALjgbfBAAI2WASk2ABWVJJAAeQhgoYBsAcwA%20XH44OHYYfCgbOFOmc4AdOxCBBggA3BYAAwmyzgABIcEtVloaJCDrw%20DR%20P1BjBnD92ABHfBIa4w6azBZItabbZ7Q4vPhvD5fH7zLSSKryTaVCxyA5wAC8zxwrze71GrJG40mMzmi0mawOANySBs8xslKFIrF4rgHPM1XmoqZevFMDsYCQmxYXhIJQA%20mM7QgplYwiQWJhdWbpHZghAUBstpSfW8aOifRGMeGMVi%20PwLVa4D5PEKRChNtdbg9aBik0g4FYgrzqum6hVOXyLqmYP44Ch7NZ7I48S5Hhj%20GgXNc4CBYpsKw1ItE4glLrX67YHEMbM9BTlygUMd2bL2dCAQHZkDo0LCF-NCJtJ3AAD4EGxaJBkO5ILQBTbT1v4gXCuDGugoQgpmCeSN8Vde2uPx03cVA6x8Px2R2Lcd3wPcoACIJQkaUcWgWfsDn-AsixLKtqgAJnTAsIDIOBgPYAEDS5OROz4AYbFnOByXmAUTTeQD4GovlHzww15HTJZS3kViY1EUgKCoGB5lY7VGT1bijSJEkyVlSl5gARiwlU5DVDUtTfdizUA0EkABAN7nmSEkRDOY4EkeEcE1OZUX-PVozFGhsAAbQAXTciVPm%20OALg5MFHnJEKAHowo7fgaCAA)

See also redux's documentation on using typescript with hooks: https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#define-typed-hooks

Answer (score 2):

My common set up includes a typesafe `AppDispatch` and typed hooks;

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, PreloadedState, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const enhancer = composeWithDevTools({ /* optional actionsBlacklist, etc */ });

const reducers = combineReducers({ /* ... */ })
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>;

export const initStore = (initState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) =>
  createStore(reducers, initState, enhancer(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
export const store = initStore();

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
type AppAction = ReturnType<typeof store.dispatch>;
export type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, any, AppAction>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

Note it will be slightly different with [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) as you `configureStore` instead `combineReducers`